# ethereum embark framework plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, embark

So I have npm app I want to add to my embark app and i did install it, however when I add it as a script in my html as it says in readme it returns 404 on that script

I have found that I also need to add it to embark.json 
so I have added it in this way

```
  "plugins": {
      "eth-lightwallet": {}
      }
```

but it returns me this error:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/embark/lib/core/plugin.js:31
  (this.pluginModule.call(this, this));
                     ^
TypeError: this.pluginModule.call is not a function
```

So I have no idea did I wrote something wrong or there is bug in eth-lightwallet, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

this is most likely a problem with embark. try updating embark to the latest version. `npm install -g embark-framework`